# Can a Sacred Fist/Master of Many Styles multiclass keep Flurry of Blows with Fuse Style?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, monk

I'm currently looking at building a Sacred Fist, with the two level dip into Monk that seems fairly common. I was thinking of using the Master of Many Styles archetype. Fuse Style mentions that it replaces Flurry of Blows (as archetype talents replace core ones of their class). So there would be no Flurry of Blows from the Monk levels I take. However, I have Flurry of Blows already from starting at level 1 in Sacred Fist.

Do I keep Flurry of Blows, or is that also gone from having Fuse Style?

Answer (score 4):

Master of many styles is a monk archetype, that alters the features of the monk class. It doesn’t have anything to do with the cleric class, or any of the cleric class’s features. So yes, fuse styles replaces the flurry of blows feature of the monk class, but it does not replace the flurry of blows feature of the sacred fist cleric.